# R-Geocoding with Address

Tags: r, geocoding, ggmap

I have 32K lines of addresses for which I have to find long/latitude values.

I'm using the code found [here](http://www.storybench.org/geocode-csv-addresses-r/). I'm so very thankful for this person to creating it but I have a question:

I'd like to edit it so that if the loop runs into an issue with the current row's address, it simply states NA in the Lat/Long fields and moves to the next one. Does anyone know how that may be accomplished? The code is below:

```
# Geocoding a csv column of "addresses" in R

#load ggmap
library(ggmap)

# Select the file from the file chooser
fileToLoad <- file.choose(new = TRUE)

# Read in the CSV data and store it in a variable 
origAddress <- read.csv(fileToLoad, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Initialize the data frame
geocoded <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through the addresses to get the latitude and longitude of each address and add it to the
# origAddress data frame in new columns lat and lon
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress))
{
  # Print("Working...")
  result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")
  origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}
# Write a CSV file containing origAddress to the working directory
write.csv(origAddress, "geocoded.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch()` to isolate the geocode warning and return a data.frame with the same structure (lon, lat, address) as `geocode()` would return.

Your code would then be

```
# Geocoding a csv column of "addresses" in R

# load ggmap
library(ggmap)

# Select the file from the file chooser
fileToLoad <- file.choose(new = TRUE)

# Read in the CSV data and store it in a variable 
origAddress <- read.csv(fileToLoad, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through the addresses to get the latitude and longitude of each address and add it to the
# origAddress data frame in new columns lat and lon
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress)) {
  result <- tryCatch(geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", source = "google"),
                     warning = function(w) data.frame(lon = NA, lat = NA, address = NA))
  origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}
# Write a CSV file containing origAddress to the working directory
write.csv(origAddress, "geocoded.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Alternatively, you can do this faster and more cleanly without the loop and error checking. However, without a reproducible example of your data there is no way to know if this will retain all of the information you need.

```
# Substituted for for loop
result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses, output = "latlona", source = "google")
origAddress <- cbind(origAddress$addresses, result)
```

Comment: I ran into this issue too...does anyone have any suggestions? 
'query max exceeded, see ?geocode.  current total = 2500'

Comment: Looking at the `geocode()` documentation, try setting `override_limit = TRUE`

Comment: `ggmap::geocode()` uses Google's geocoding services by default, which itself has a limit of 2,500 queries per day. When using their service through `ggmap` you are still bound by their terms of service.

Comment: You may be able to use a Google API key to exceed the standard limits. Try https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: @BenFasoli There is still a limit though, so depending on what Walker is considering, perhaps a paid license is needed.

Comment: @Walker Try this code, it takes into account the 2500 limit and pings the server until the task is completed (however many days it takes) https://www.r-bloggers.com/batch-geocoding-with-r-and-google-maps/