# Adding longitude and latitude with google-style search queries of addresses

Tags: r, geocoding, ggmap

I want to add longitudes and latitudes of specific addresses. My input data is a vector of 1540 addresses (which should not exceed the daily limit of queries as I understood) of the form:

```
                                             gmapsinput
1                        Carl-Zeiss-str.+85+73431+Aalen
2                             Ulmerstr.+150+73431+Aalen
3             Wilhelmstr.+50+73433+Aalen+Wasseralfingen
4  Hubertus-Liebrecht-str.+40+88400+Biberach+Aspach+Süd
5                       Waldseerstr.+143+88400+Biberach
6       Obertürkheimerstr.+82+73733+Esslingen+Mettingen
7     Stauffenbergstr.+29+73730+Esslingen+Oberesslingen
8           Ignaz-Gfell-Platz+3+79868+Feldberg+Bärental
9                             Luzinweg+4+17258+Feldberg
10           Carl-Kistner-str.+2+79115+Freiburg+Haslach
```

If I set the api key by `set.api.key()` (where my specific key works with `gmapsdistance` calculations, so it cannot be the key not working) and try the code found here [R-Geocoding with Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290940/r-geocoding-with-address) it does not work, giving the following error:
`Warnung: Geocoding "Carl-Zeiss-str.+8..." failed with error: This API project is not authorized to use this API.`
My code is this one:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(gmaps))
{
  # Print("Working...")
  result <- geocode(gmaps$gmapsinput[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")
  gmaps$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  gmaps$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  gmaps$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The problem seems to be with registering your API key rather than your R code

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too, but my API key works for queries done with the `gmapsdistance` library.

Comment: But maybe it is just not the same, as I read here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/readme/README.html.

Comment: This why I used `geocode_OSM` from `tmap`, for my recent project which uses `openstreetmap` for finding `lat long` information. You can try it, it works fine with my use case

Comment: Thank you so much a@Mohan Govindasamy! This saves the problem and so much easier doesn't even need a credit card.